# How to write single-line from multi-line blocks in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, methods, block

I'm trying to write the single-line block for each entity from array (@controller) and the purpose of this single block is yield the [n] element from the controller array, n is an accessor, now I figured something like that:

```
def for_controller
 controller = @controllers.first[n] 
 yield controller
end
```

The single block I wrote unfortunately doesn't work, but the multi-line block below works perfectly in the loop.

```
def for_all_controllers
  @controllers.each do |controller|
    yield controller
  end
end
```

To make the question more clear:

```
@controllers[0] should yield => something_1
@controllers[1] should yield => something_2
@controllers[n] should yield => something_(n+1)
```

How can i get this to work?

Comment: In your first method, you are using `@controllers.first[n]`, but there is no parameter `n` to the method `for_controller`. Where does `n` come from?

Comment: Maybe you are just looking for `@controllers.first` without the `[n]` ?

Comment: read the following answers

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
def for_controller
 yield @controllers[n]
end
```

Comment: maybe :) but the n is an accessor, do we need exactly use the n on the method declaration? if yes, please explain why, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code looks like wrong.

`@controllers.first[n]`

This gets n'th element from the Array which returns by `@controller.first`.

But in your question, you said:

> yield the [n] element from the controller array

I think you are expect the data structure (a), not (b).

```
(a)
@controllers = [
  'something',    # <= @controller.first returns this element, as you expected
  'something',
  'something'
]

(b)
@controller = [
  ['something', 'something', 'something'],
  ['something', 'something', 'something'],
  ['something', 'something', 'something']
]
```

I think you should try below:

`@controllers.first(n)`

It returns the first n'th elements from @controller. Is it a result you expected, right?

Comment: n - is any element in the array, for instance I want to yield @controllers[0] it should yield => something_1; I want to yield @controllers[1]  it should yield => something_2; I want to yield @controllers[n]  it should yield => something_n. I hope the target is clear now?

Comment: If you want to access one element of @controller, `.first` does not need: `@controller[n]` works. If you want to access multiple elements of @controller, try `@controller[n,m]`.

Comment: I need to access elements sequentially, I've something like n =0; n= n+1; so every loop variable n, in another function increasing by 1. So , I need a function which doing yield every @controller[n], how to organize the function?